# Cannot access the file because it is being use by another process

Tags: c#

I know, this question already been asked in many places repeatedly. But I've tried to google it and check this site for solution, but still come short. I'm still encountering this issue even after using all of the suggested solutions.

Basically, I have two separate programs. The function of each program is something like below.

1. **ProgramA** - Function: Constantly update to the source file(txt)
2. *ProgramB** - Function: Constantly copy the source file to destination location.

With ProgramB, I want to sort of simulate doing the ctrl+c operation. Hence I am trying to archive where by I can update the file and operator can copy it as well.

Here is what I've tried so far. Below is sample program to test the functionality.

## ProgramA

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // just prepare the data
    List<string> tempList = new List<string>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 50000; i++)
    {
        tempList.Add(string.Format("xxx_{0}", i.ToString()));
    }

    try
    {
        // just to simulate constart update
        for (int j = 0; j < 20000; j++)
        {
            using (FileStream file = new FileStream(tmpFilePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(file))
                {
                    foreach (string tmpName in tempList)
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine(tmpName);
                    }
                    sw.Close();
                }
                file.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

## ProgramB

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string source = @"C:\temp\test.txt";
    string dest = @"C:\temp\dest\test.txt";
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            File.Copy(source, dest, true);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you know if your file is opened or another program is using it? what you can do is to add a check to see if it is opened or not

Comment: hmm..perhaps i can do so. Or do a catch IO exception in FileStream file = new FileStream(tmpFilePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite)???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using [File.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9706cfs5.aspx), try using a [FileStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5h0z48dh.aspx) and copying the bits yourself.  The above code will get an error, as [File.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9706cfs5.aspx) does not specify what [FileShare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare.aspx) permissions it sets on the file.

Comment: Hi,thanks for your reply. Basically ProgramA is my side which i need to code. ProgramB is i want to sort of simulate operator doing ctrl+c operation. Hence i trying to archive where by i can update the file and operator can copy it as well.

Comment: If ProgramB is supposed to simulate an operator out of your control, then you need to have ProgramA loop/block on access to the file.  You can't guarantee that ProgramB does not open the file in exclusive mode.

Comment: I guess you are right. Probably my only choice is to catch exception or check the file is being use and do retry.

Answer (score 1):

This should be a comment, but it's too long.  it's more of a design suggestion than a coding answer.

I'm assuming that both of these programs are on a timer, or on a FileSystemWatcher which means that there's a lack of predictability.  You can't guarantee when program A wil lbe called or when program B will be called, in relation to the time it takes to do the read/write operations.

In other words, you can't predict when a file will be locked because of inherent lack of control in design.

If it's at all possible, I'd combine the two programs.  Really, what I'd assume you want is for the file to be copied (Program b functionality) as soon as program A is done writing to it.  There's no (obvious) reason you can't code it so that program A immediately copies the file after writing to it.

If lack of predictability is at the root of the issue, remove the unpredictability.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. You are sort of right what i'm trying to archive. However, ProgramB is i want to simulate operator doing Ctrl+C operation. (As you suspected, i don't know when Operator will do Ctrl+C). So that is why i trying to archive on ProgramA where it allow program to continue to update at the same time Operator can do a Ctrl+C operation

Answer (score 1):

If both of these programs are running on the same machine, you could use a named [Mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f55ddskf.aspx) and lock when you are writing to, and copying the file.

So in Program A you would add

```
using (Mutex m = new Mutex(false,"MyMutex"))
{
    m.WaitOne();
    // Your file writing code
    m.ReleaseMutex();
}
```

And do the same thing around your file copy code.

Comment: +1.  This solves the general case much better than my file-specific answer.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. Is a great suggestion. However ProgramB is sort of like simulating operator doing Ctrl+C operation. So basically i want ProgramA continue update the file while at the same time Operator can copy it. (hmm..i think i screw up with the voting system in this site)